# Notification count in title for iOS-app

Tags: bug, ios-app

Recent version of iOS-app shows me a weird indicator near the post title. This happened after opening post in Chrome and going back to the app.

What is this and how it correlate with notification count in the left panel?

> [image: count in title]

Tapping on it just navigates me back (`<`), as if there is no count indicator at all.

- App Version: 1.7.0
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)

Comment: This is a bug.  In portrait, we're collapsing the menu and I'm experimenting with this as an indicator that there's new content in the menu.  Somehow it leaked into the detail navigation controller.

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed in 1.7.0.1.

I'm not sure what exactly was causing it to show up in the detail view controller, but I've added more aggressive logic for updating the navigation item.

As to what that indicator is...

In portrait mode (or any level of split screen), I'm collapsing the menu and basically making the app look like an iPhone, except that the inbox and achievements are still in the menu.

This presents a problem in that now you can't see when the totals update.  In that case, I'm putting an icon in the top left corner to indicate that there is menu content.  I was trying to be cute and put the indicator in the back button like the mail app, but the idiom doesn't really work here.  In the next build, it will be its own separate navigation item that causes the menu to open:

> [image: Screenshot showing the open menu and the indicator icon]